# Magento 2: Product images are not generated in media cache on importing products

Tags: magento2, product-images, importexport, media-images, import-products

Facing weird issue for 2-3 days. Images are not showing on frontend Whenever I import new products using firebear module or default importer.

I tried php bin/magento catalog:image:resize, Unfortunately it didn't generated images in media cache.

However, if I upload images manually, it shows up on frotnend.

I have spent enough time in debugging, unfortunately not getting root cases.

Magento version is 2.3.4 and we have migrated from Magemojo to MGT recently.

Please help on it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the column you are importing by csv?
Can you put a screenshot here with your original question?

Comment: @SaurabhDwivedi , I am importing all the columns including images from CSV